# Request JSON data from Facebook Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, jsonp

I don't get what am I doing wrong here

> [Live example at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/udexog/2/edit#preview)

If you see the original url, we get something:

link: http://graph.facebook.com/http://stackoverflow.com

*data retrieved*

```
{
  "id": "http://stackoverflow.com",
  "shares": 3588,
  "comments": 2
}
```

But I can't get the data, I always get `[object object]` and I have no clue (night time here, brain does not wanna work this time) whats going on :-/

am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has returned an object which you have to iterate.

I updated your code to show this. http://jsbin.com/udexog/3/edit